# Javascript: How to take input from search bar?

Tags: javascript, input, filter, searchbar

I am trying to take user input from the search bar and display results after the user presses enter or the search button. For example, a user enters an input and presses the search button. Afterwards, the page displays the documents by name searched. How may I do this?

P.S. I've already done filtering as an example, but I don't know why I'm struggling with a search bar.

HTML

```
        <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
          <div class="form-group">
            <input text="text" id='searchQuery' class="form-control" placeholder="Search" size="60">
          </div>
          <button type="submit" id='searchButton' class="btn btn-default" aria-label="Submit">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          </button>
        </form>
```

Javascript Filter Function (fully working example) that takes a selection and searches by input

```
function addDocumentFilterAsData (option, value, element) {
  switch (option) {
  case 'name':
    element.data('filter', function (doc) {
      return doc.getName().includes(value);
    });
    break
  case 'owner':
    element.data('filter', function (doc) {
      return doc.getOwners().has(value);
    });
    break;
  case 'tag':
    element.data('filter', function (doc) {
      return doc.getTags().has(value);
    });
    break;
  case 'date':
    element.data('filter', function (doc) {
      return doc.getUploadDate().toDateString().includes(value);
    });
    break;
  default:
    console.error('Unknown filter option:', criterion.val());
  }
}

//For filtering documents, on view documents page
function generateDocumentFilterItem (pane, filterList) {
  let filterItem = $('<li/>');
  let criterion = $('<select/>')
      .append($('<option/>').text('name'))
      .append($('<option/>').text('owner'))
      .append($('<option/>').text('tag'))
      .append($('<option/>').text('date'));
  let pattern = $('<input/>', { type: 'text' });

  //button to add a filter
  let addFilterButton = $('<button/>', {
    type: 'button',
    click: function () {
      addDocumentFilterAsData(criterion.val(), pattern.val(), filterItem);
      addFilterButton.detach();
      filterItem.append(updateFilterButton);
      filterItem.after(generateDocumentFilterItem(pane, filterList));
      refreshDocumentList(pane, filterList);
    }
  });

  addFilterButton.append('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span>');

  //button to update an already added filter
  let updateFilterButton = $('<button/>', {
    type: 'button',
    click: function () {
      addDocumentFilterAsData(criterion.val(), pattern.val(), filterItem);
      refreshDocumentList(pane, filterList);
    }
  });

  updateFilterButton.append('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh" aria-hidden="true"></span>');

  filterItem.append(criterion).append(pattern).append(addFilterButton);
  criterion.before('');
  criterion.after('');
  return filterItem;
}
```

Extra info: 'Show Documents' button that displays all documents when pressed.

```
  $('#listDocumentsButton').click(function() {

    let listDocumentsPane = $('#listDocumentsPane');
    listDocumentsPane.empty().show().siblings().hide();

    let filterList = $('<ol/>', {
      'class': 'document-filter-list'
    }).appendTo(listDocumentsPane);

    let documentListPane = $('<div/>', {
      'class': 'document-list-pane'
    }).appendTo(listDocumentsPane);

    filterList.append(generateDocumentFilterItem(documentListPane, filterList));
    refreshDocumentList(documentListPane, filterList);
    $('#tagsMain').children().empty();
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using JQuery in your methods, you could just use

```
$('#searchQuery').val();
```

or assign it to a variable and perhaps use it instead of the value in your filter

```
var value = $('#searchQuery').val();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just say: `document.getElementById(id).value;` id is your id